# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError material selection list

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Before throw tomatoes to me, please read it. I've found tons of topics with same error  here about this problem and solution such 'AfterViewChecked' and 'AfterContentChecked' simply don't work, cause it just clear an error in console and I can't get desirable result.

I have two material selection lists with data like next

```
categories1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

categories2 = [{'id':'1'}, {'id':'2'}, {'id':'3'}, {'id':'4'}, {'id':'5'}]
```

This method of selection works fine:

```
     <mat-selection-list dense #categoryId [formControlName]="'categoryId'">
         <mat-list-option *ngFor="let category of categories1
                          [value]="category.id
                          [selected]="selectedCategories(category.id)" >
         {{category.name}}
       </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>



ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      categoryId: new FormControl([], []),
    })
    let array = ['2', '3']

    this.form.get('categoryId').patchValue(item.categoryId);
  }

 selectedCategories(id) {
     return this.form.get('categoryId').value.some(item => item === id);
  }
```

However this selection list returns me an error:

```
   <mat-selection-list dense #categoryId [formControlName]="'categoryId'">
         <mat-list-option *ngFor="let category of categories2 
                          [value]="{id: category.id}"
                          [selected]="selectedCategories(category.id)" >
         {{category.name}}
       </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>



ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      categoryId: new FormControl([], []),
    })
    let array = [{'id':'2'}, {'id':'3']

    this.form.get('categoryId').patchValue(item.categoryId);
  }

 selectedCategories(id) {
     return this.form.get('categoryId').value.some(item => item.id === id);
  }
```

So could somebody explain me, what is going on here ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you probably add an error log?